# Azure CI pipeline trigger not working after git instance migration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I have few CI and CD pipelines in azure devOps project in which CI pipelines connect to github enterprise repository to fetch the code.
CI pipelines were invoked by the trigger whenever there is a change in main branch of repository.

This was working fine until our git repository instance was changed. All our git repositories are migrated to the new instance.

I have updated the service connection, to point to the new git instance and manually invoked CI pipelines and tested. It worked fine.

But the issue is now with automatic triggering of CI pipelines. It is not working now.
I tried remove and add git service connections and repository details inside CI pipeline and enabled trigger, but still it is not getting automatically invoked whenever there is a change in repository.

What could be the reason for this ? I already removed and added the git repository details in CI pipeline, still that does not work. Is there anything I missed out?  Any leads appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue and fixed. It was error with web hook in the repository.
Updated the webhook and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "Override the YAML trigger from here" setting for the types of trigger (Continuous integration or Pull request validation) available for your repo." in the Triggers UI.

If it does not work, please create a new pipeline to check if it works.

For more information, you could refer to: [troubleshooting failing triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github-enterprise?view=azure-devops#failing-triggers)

Comment: I am not using yaml file for the build, added activities in the azure portal only and I didnt see the mentioned option on the trigger tab. Attached the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Please choose the "Pull request validation" to check.